# How to get around the \x1a character (or similar characters) in a hash (Crypto++ Library)?

Tags: c++, hash

I am relatively new to programming and this project is one of the very first projects that I am doing in my own time.

I am basically trying to make a login registration program that hashes user-entered data and stores it in a text file. The login option basically accesses that text file and compares it with the user entered data to see if there exists any such username and password combinations. The registration option basically writes the user data into the file. I am not very far into the project since I want to add a few more "features" to the program so it works a bit better. Currently, however, I encountered a slight problem while reading the data from the text file for the login option. Basically, one of the hashed passwords stored in the text file contains `\x1a` as a part of its hash. I think the program always ends whenever it reads this sub-control character since it reaches the end of the file. What I want to know is how to avoid a hash that has such a character.

I am using the crypto++ library (I am not too familiar with it).

The hash function:

```
void hashingFunc(string originalPass, string& hashedPass) {

   using namespace CryptoPP;

   SHA3_256 hash;

   hash.Update((const byte*)originalPass.data(), originalPass.size());
   encryptedPass.resize(hash.DigestSize());
   hash.Final((byte*)&encryptedPass[0]);
   

}
```

The read function:

```
void readFileFunc(fstream& outputFile, const string FILE_NAME, string userNameHash, string passWordHash) {
   string localUserHash;
   string localPassHash;


   if (!outputFile) {
      cout << "File containing login information failed to open. Please try again." << endl;
      cout << "If the problem persists, check file name and location." << endl;
      cout << "File Name in the system: " << FILE_NAME << endl;
   }
   else {
      while (outputFile) {
         if (outputFile.eof())
            break;

         getline(outputFile, localUserHash);
         getline(outputFile, localPassHash);

         if (localUserHash == userNameHash) {
            if (localPassHash == passWordHash) {
               cout << "Successful Login!" << endl;
            }

         }
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: `/x1a` -- That is the End-of-file marker in a Windows/DOS text file.  Are you sure your issue isn't one of reading text files incorrectly?

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: it's `\x1a`, not `/x1a`, and you can read any byte values if you open the file in binary mode

Comment: @phuclv I am sorry I used the regular slash in the question, however, it is the \x1a character.

Also, I have never opened a file in Binary, I just have one question, how would you compare information from a binary file with a normal string

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think so since I have opened files in a similar way in other projects too.

Comment: if you read a binary file then why read it as a string? Just use a std::vector<char> instead

Comment: @MuhammadZaid -- *Currently, however, I encountered a slight problem while reading the data from the text file for the login option.* -- There is no way to encounter an ASCII 26 (Ctrl-Z, hex 1A) if you opened the file in text mode **and the program is running under Windows**.   Note the emphasis on the last phrase -- are you running your program in Windows, or another OS where text files are *not* terminated with a 26?  Are you using a Windows generated text file, and reading the file in, say, Linux?  Note that none of your code shows how you opened the file.

Comment: @phuclv I might have miscommunicated; I am not reading the info from the file to a string. I am comparing the user entered information (a string) with the information read from the file.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am reading it in the Windows operating system on the Visual Studio IDE. The \x1a was a character from the hash function. I just stored in it the text file.

Comment: @MuhammadZaid You can't store that character in a Windows text file -- you can try, but it will take you nowhere.  Why are you using text files to begin with?  You should be working in binary throughout.  If you want a pure ASCII representation and want text files, change the encryption string that contains the `\x1a` to Base64 and store that in the text file.  That's what is usually done in the real world where ASCII / text is required, and you have binary data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have never worked in binary before so I did not think of it as a possible solution. So does the program automatically store the character in binary in the file if I were to add ios::binary to the stream mode? And is it not recognized in the program?

Thank you for the info!

Comment: @MuhammadZaid If you stored the program in binary, then you can write any character to the file.  But is your solution really this, or is it what I stated in the previous comment, i.e. turn the string into [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and store that in the text file?  You're using Crypto++, so there are functions that do this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will try both so that I can gain knowledge regarding both the library and the binary mode.